# error while calling stored procedure: You are using safe update

Tags: mysql

I am trying to call a stored procedure, but I am getting : Error Code: 1175 You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column

Here is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `SystemSetting` (
  `SettingName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `SettingValue` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Deleted` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`SettingName`),
  KEY `PK_SystemSetting` (`SettingName`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and the procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `SystemSettingCommit` (IN p_SettingName varchar(45), IN p_SettingValue varchar(45), OUT p_Status varchar(55)) 
BEGIN
SET p_Status = '00000';

IF (p_SettingValue IS NULL) OR (RTRIM(LTRIM(p_SettingValue)) = '') THEN
    SET p_Status = `StatusConcat`(p_Status, '10016');
END IF; 

IF (p_SettingName IS NULL) OR (RTRIM(LTRIM(p_SettingName)) = '') THEN
    SET p_Status = `StatusConcat`(p_Status, '10017');
END IF; 

IF (p_Status = '00000') THEN
    IF ((SELECT COUNT(`SettingName`) FROM `SystemSetting` WHERE (`SettingName` = p_SettingName)) > 0) THEN
        UPDATE `SystemSetting` SET `SettingValue` = p_SettingValue WHERE (`SettingName` = p_SettingName);
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO `SystemSetting` (`SettingName`, `SettingValue`) VALUES (p_SettingName, p_SettingValue);
    END IF;
END IF; 
END$$

DELIMITER;
```

and this is how I call it:

```
CALL `SystemSettingCommit` ('Setting1', 'Value1', @Status);
```

Comment: CREATE FUNCTION `StatusConcat` (p_CurrentStatus varchar(45), p_NewStatus varchar(45)) RETURNS varchar(45)
BEGIN
 RETURN CASE WHEN p_CurrentStatus = '00000' THEN p_NewStatus ELSE CONCAT(CONCAT(p_CurrentStatus, ', '), p_NewStatus) END;
END$$

Comment: I can not reproduce the problem. How do you make the call to the stored procedure, from the command line, from an IDE?

Comment: MySQL Workbench 6 
CALL `SystemSettingCommit` ('Setting1', 'Value1', @Status);

Comment: Check that the stored procedure is really trying to update the table shown in the question, not the same table in another schema that perhaps has another definition.

Comment: I have added the CALL `DatabaseName`. infront, same result.

Comment: Using MySQL 5.5.32 and Workbench 6.0.6, I created the table and stored procedure as shown in the question. When called the stored procedure everything works as expected.

The variable @@SQL_SAFE_UPDATES is set to 1.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
```

Or follow this in workbench:

- Go to Edit --> Preferences
- Click "SQL Queries" tab and uncheck "Safe Updates" check box
- Query --> Reconnect to Server
- Now execute your sql query

Comment: That will make the error go away yes, but I still want to know why it is occuring.

Comment: Well, I guess MySQL is being protective, as sometimes UPDATE statements are vulnerable(When ran without any WHERE clause by mistake!). 'SettingName' is not a key column here! Restricting by the key-column-condition-check may save damage by novice users, what say?

Comment: PRIMARY KEY (`SettingName`),
KEY `PK_SystemSetting` (`SettingName`)